# Using @apollo/client from() with onError() instead of concat() without onError() does not work on android device

Tags: react-native, expo, apollo, apollo-client

`react-native` expo app, scanning the QR code in the terminal with the Expo app on my phone to launch the app, after starting the app with `npm run web` in my machine's terminal.

Both of the following cases work fine on my machine's browser. The one using `onError()` (the 2nd example) gets a "Network Error" on my phone and the apollo client http request is not made. The 1st example works fine on my phone.

Working `App.js`:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { customColours as colors } from './src/utils';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NavigationBar } from './src/components';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import NetworkLogger from 'react-native-network-logger';
import { startNetworkLogging } from 'react-native-network-logger';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, ApolloProvider, concat, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { HomeScreen, LogInScreen, SignUpScreen } from './src/screens';
import { GRAPHQL_URL, NETWORK_LOGGER } from '@env';


const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink(async (operation, forward) => {
  const authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');

  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: authToken
    }
  }));

  return forward(operation);
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: GRAPHQL_URL });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink)
});

const networkLoggerIsEnabled = NETWORK_LOGGER === 'true';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors
};

export default function App() {
  networkLoggerIsEnabled && startNetworkLogging();
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              header: props => <NavigationBar {...props} />
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen component={HomeScreen} name="Home" options={{ title: 'Home' }} />
            <Stack.Screen component={LogInScreen} name="LogIn" options={{ title: 'Log In'}} />
            <Stack.Screen component={SignUpScreen} name='SignUp' options={{ title: 'Sign Up' }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
          {networkLoggerIsEnabled && <NetworkLogger />}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

Non-working `App.js`:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { customColours as colors } from './src/utils';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NavigationBar } from './src/components';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import NetworkLogger from 'react-native-network-logger';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
import { startNetworkLogging } from 'react-native-network-logger';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, ApolloProvider, from, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { HomeScreen, LogInScreen, SignUpScreen } from './src/screens';
import { GRAPHQL_URL, NETWORK_LOGGER } from '@env';


const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink(async (operation, forward) => {
  const authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');

  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: authToken
    }
  }));

  return forward(operation);
});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
      )
    );

  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: GRAPHQL_URL });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: from([authMiddleware, errorLink, httpLink])
});

const networkLoggerIsEnabled = NETWORK_LOGGER === 'true';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors
};

export default function App() {
  networkLoggerIsEnabled && startNetworkLogging();
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              header: props => <NavigationBar {...props} />
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen component={HomeScreen} name="Home" options={{ title: 'Home' }} />
            <Stack.Screen component={LogInScreen} name="LogIn" options={{ title: 'Log In'}} />
            <Stack.Screen component={SignUpScreen} name='SignUp' options={{ title: 'Sign Up' }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
          {networkLoggerIsEnabled && <NetworkLogger />}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

The difference between the two is that the second one uses `from()` instead of `concat()` and has an extra `link` in the chain: `errorLink`.

I *have* to use `from()` if I want to use more than two links - `concat()` is limited to 2 links.

`errorLink` documentation: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-error

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-wordlist-mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "start": "expo start",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.11",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-network-logger": "^1.14.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint": "^8.37.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

EDIT:

Using the following works, so it looks like the problem isn't with `from()` - the problem must be something to do with `errorLink`:

```js
const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink(async (operation, forward) => {
  const authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');

  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: authToken
    }
  }));

  return forward(operation);
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: GRAPHQL_URL });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: from([authMiddleware, httpLink])
});
```